# ajax function doesn't seem to pass value to my php page

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

i am creating a facebook like posting system.. as of the moment i am having problem of deleting the post from the database.

this is the javascript code:

```
      $('#delete_post').live("click",function()
      {
               var ID = $(this).attr("class");
               //alert(ID);
               var parent = $(this).parent();

               if(confirm("Are you sure to delete this Comment?"))
       {
                  $(".bar"+ID).slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});

                  $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
              url: "post_delete.php",
              data: "msg_id="+ID,
                          success: function(html){
                            $('#'+ID).remove();
                            //$(this).html('<meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"1; URL=insert.php\">');
                          }});
        }
```

this is my php code for deleting the post:

```
     <?php
       $msg_id= $_REQUEST['msg_id'];
       $msg_id= $_POST['msg_id'];

       echo $msg_id;

       @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'wall');

                            if(mysqli_connect_errno())
                        {
                echo "Error! Could not connect to database. Reset fields.";
                exit;
                }

     $sql = "DELETE * FROM messages WHERE msg_id='$msg_id'";
     $result = $db->query($sql);

     $db->close();
       }
      ?>
```

i don't understand why i wasn't able to delete the post via ajax function.. i am sure it could get the id but i think it can't call the php page.
is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: What does your javascript debugger say ? was the request sent ? what about including some debugging in your PHP ? was the correct value sent / received ?

Comment: Getting the class probably isnt the best way to do this - I would suggest that each entry has a unique ID and you use that to communicate with the server - Classes are meant to be shared by lots of DOM elements

Comment: Also, you're binding `.live()` on element by id, I don't think that you have one delete button.

Comment: i don't have a javascript debugger.. i have added some debugging in my php also last time but yet it doesn't work..  yes i get the correct value.. i get the right msg_id

Comment: have u tried to remove @ from connect to database? Maybe there will be an error?

Comment: @suffocationkills check out [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for javascript debugging ... so your PHP is executed but doesnt remove the entry from the DB ? is msg_id numeric ? if so remove the quotes around the value from the query

Comment: what do you mean i'm  binding .live() on element by id? i'm using it's class..

Comment: @devdRew i've tried removing @ but there's no error.. does ot mean, it wasn't able to connect to the php page?

Comment: `$('#delete_post').live()` that's mean that you bind an event handler on elements with id `delete_post`, if there will be not one element with such id, you would have bugs. How many elemetns $('#delete_post') you have on you page?

Comment: can you put some `echo 'I found the page post_delete.php';` in the beginning of the post_delete.php, for debug, and answer if it works. If you can't see what you have responded by server, try `<script type="text/javascript">alert('I found!');</script>` pasting into the beginning of the post_delete.php.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
data: { 'msg_id' : ID }
```

That's better and easier then just a string.

Another problem may be caused by binding handler on element by id `$('#delete_post')`, if there would be few elements with id like that (`delete_post`), only first occurance will be working one.

Comment: The [documentation on ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server) says that you can use either ... how / why is it "better" ?

Comment: For readability, for pre-construction, for modification. Choose what you like... it's much easier to read `{ 'v1' : 'some', 'v2' : 'some2' }` then `v1=' + some1 + '&v2=' + some2`.

Comment: I sad that's better, I didn't told that it's gonna fix the problem. I am waiting for debugger info.

Comment: I'll keep that for the future, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your SQL `DELETE` syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html
2. You've mixed up the use of ids and classes - ids should be unique (like post id) and classes may be not (like multiple "delete post" buttons)
3. Your `ID` variable is most probably out of scope in your $.ajax success handler, so the post will not be removed from DOM even if it is removed from the DB succesfully.

Comment: Yes, it's the MySQL delete that's wrong.
it should be DELETE FROM, not DELETE * FROM